# How do I invoke different actions for different instances of the same jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm just getting to grips with jquery-ui, and the dialog function.  I've got the basics working like this:

```
$("#jquery-confirm").dialog({
  dialogClass: "jQdialog",
  autoOpen : false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Yes: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      // do something for yes;
    },
    No : function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      // do something for no;
    }
  }
});
```

Then I can call up the dialog:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
    OpenCustomDialog("Title 1");
});

function OpenCustomDialog(title) {
  $("#jquery-confirm").dialog("option", "title", title);
  $("#jquery-confirm").dialog('open');
}
```

This is fine, but now I want to use the same dialog, but specify different actions attached to the Yes/No buttons:

```
$("#button2").click(function() {
    OpenCustomDialog("Title 2");
});
```

How can I change the action of the Yes/No buttons, depending on HTML element (button1/button2) which called the dialog?

My best guesses are callback functions and/or closures, but I cant get my head around it.

Comment: you could define seperate functions for each event and bind them wanted. when switching the method, just unbind the previous event and rebind with a new handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classic and simple way is to create a new dialog instead of reusing the old one. Since you're not doing that in the question, I'll assume you don't want to do it for whatever reason; so, instead you can use a `data` attribute:

```
var callbacks = {
    yes: {
        b1: function() { /*do something*/ }
        b2: function() { /*do something*/ }
    },
    no: {
        b1: function() { /*do something else*/ }
        b2: function() { /*do something else*/ }
    }
};

// ... etc.

  buttons: {
    Yes: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      callbacks.yes[$(this).data("callback-target")]();
    },
    No : function() {
      $(this).dialog('close');
      callbacks.no[$(this).data("callback-target")]();
    }
  }

// .. etc.

$("#button1").click(function() {
    OpenCustomDialog("Title 1", "b1");
});

function OpenCustomDialog(title, callback) {
  $("#jquery-confirm").dialog("option", "title", title);
  $("#jquery-confirm").data("callback-target", callback);
  $("#jquery-confirm").dialog('open');
}
```

Also consider that binding the `title` and `callback` parameters in `OpenCustomDialog` as data attributes on the buttons will make the handler look cleaner

Comment: Thanks for your answer(s), that's very helpful.  I had considered using separate dialogs, but I was trying to be "efficient" - I have four or five places where I want to use different prompts to return a yes/no answer